# How to change item in a RecyclerView in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying something similar to like/unlike feature of Instagram. But whenever I try to click the star in the Recycler View, the white star does not change to red star as shown below:

The white changes to red and then to white again.

[image]

The `MyAdapter` class is:

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemViewHolder>{

    private List<ListItem> listItems;

    MyAdapter(List<ListItem> listItems){
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ListItemViewHolder(TestListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ListItemViewHolder holder, int position) {

        ListItem listItem = listItems.get(position);
        holder.binding.name.setText(listItem.getTitle());
        holder.binding.post.setText(listItem.getDescription());

        if(listItem.isClick()){
            holder.binding.redStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.binding.whiteStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            holder.binding.redStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.binding.whiteStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        clicklitn(holder);

    }

    public void clicklitn(final ListItemViewHolder holder){
        holder.binding.redStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.binding.redStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.binding.whiteStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("CLICK DETECTION", "Red Star click detected");

                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        holder.binding.whiteStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.binding.redStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.binding.whiteStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("CLICK DETECTION", "White Star click detected");

                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting `isClick` when stars are clicked. I don't know how your class hierarchy is, however you should do something like this:

```java
    public void clicklitn(final ListItemViewHolder holder){
        holder.binding.redStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.binding.redStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.binding.whiteStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("CLICK DETECTION", "Red Star click detected");
                //set item isClick to false
                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
        holder.binding.whiteStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.binding.redStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.binding.whiteStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Log.d("CLICK DETECTION", "White Star click detected");
                //set item isClick to true
                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your else part resets your colour change.

```
if(listItem.isClick()){
    holder.binding.redStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.binding.whiteStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
    holder.binding.redStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.binding.whiteStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Since, you define your onClick operations inside clicklitn function, you don't need the if else here.

Comment: Actually the data is being retrieved from a database. So each time an object is retrieved from database, it checks if the object returns true for clicked. If the item is already clicked, then it makes the red star visible else it makes the white star visible. Is there a way to implement the function clicklitn along with if else?

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it from quick and simple method**

```
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(position);
```

position of your item what you want to change.